# initializing NSImage in swift

Tags: macos, swift, nsimage

Trying to initializing NSImage object.

```
var image = NSImage("Images/pause_work_normal.png")
```

But get an error: ambiguous reference to member NSImage.init

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
  var image:NSImage!
  image = NSImage(named:"Images/pause_work_normal.png")
```

Or the short way

```
var image = NSImage(named:"Images/pause_work_normal.png")
```

Comment: Thanks, it's work. When i used first init methodin documentetion with -filename:, I had this error.

Comment: @Lamar Error: Use of undeclared type 'NSImage' in Swift.